# login screen for netbeans desktop database applicatoin

Tags: java, netbeans

I created a simple java desktop database application in netbeans and as i am running the application it gets connect to the mysql database and is working properly. But now i want to create a log-in screen for it by which, different mysql users could log in to the database.
your help will be my pleasure.

Thank you,

Comment: A vague question. I can't actually see what's your specific problem. Can you give more details?

Comment: I created my java database application through netbeans built-in features(netbeans->create new project wizard->desktop application->database application) i mean i have not used any coding. The database connection is not based on java codes it is set during creating the applicaton"create new project wizard". now i want to change this build-in database connection to a login screen connection, because i don't want to login with just one database user but i want to login with different database users to my application.

Comment: The wizard creates the code for you. I'd say the first step for you would be to lookup where the generated code is. Based on the code it should be possible to clarify this question so it can be answered.

Comment: The point is that i can find every other netbeans generated codes rather than the database connection codes, just i can see the generated database name under netbeans services window->Database notion as below:
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbname[root on Default schema]

Comment: Some of the code is hidden from you by folding in. Or maybe the configuration is in an XML file. Can you make a text search in your project for your database and see where it shows up?

Comment: my application name is "DesktopApplication1" and i opened DesktopApplication1view.java(which is the applications main form) then i expanded the hidden generated code notion and tried to find(ctrl+f) any of "database,conn,sql,jdbc.mysql.root" but i could not find anything.

Comment: is this the only file? hmmm - then maybe someone else knows. I'm not familiar with the inner workings of netbeans.

Comment: there are some other files but they don't contain the database connection information. i am stack i really don't know what to do to change the existence connection to a login screen database connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
String user=jTextField1.getText();

String pwd= new String (jPasswordField1.getPassword());
if(user.equals("user") && pwd.equals("pass"))

    new NewJFrame2().setVisible(true);


    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Invalid!");
        jTextField1.setText("");
        jPasswordField1.setText("");

    }
```